# Open html file located inside my application using WebView

Tags: android, webview

I am just started Android application development. Here i have a simple Activity which contains a WebView. It works fine when i try to open a website (like http://www.google.com). But i want to open a html file (assume index.html) file which i created in my application's 'res' directory. Full path is 'res/base/index.html'. Then how to open this file in my WebView.?

Working :

```
webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Not Working :

```
webview.loadUrl("./res/base/index.html");
```

Please help me. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put the file in your `/assets` directory and use:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Comment: where to create that assets directory, inside res directory? I am not able to create at level of /res...

Comment: @MohsinSaeed just create a normal folder below `main/src` with `assets` as a name, Android Studio will recognize it.

Answer (score 8):

First you copy the index.html file to assets folder in your project and then try this, It might help you

```
public class WebViewDemoActivity extends Activity {  

    private WebView mWebView;  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.web_view_layout);  

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view_id);  
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Not working. I am getting this error :

http://i.imgur.com/o42fL.png

Is it need ask file read permission along with Internet access too.?

Comment: Add Internet Permission in manifest file as <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. The file is misplaced. Thanks for the answer mate :)

Answer (score 5):

Try something like

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");
```

Comment: Not working. I added the file and did exactly like this. Is it need ask file read permission along with Internet access too.?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. The file is misplaced. Thanks for the answer mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to necessarily put your file inside the assets folder. You can just append `"file:///"` as a prefix of your file path.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that there is no need to put into assests. Having `path` to the file it can be loaded in the following way:

```
val url = Uri.fromFile(File(path)).toString()
web_view.loadUrl(url)
```